# Trouble installing Google plugin for Eclipse: Unable to get past accepting licenses

Tags: eclipse, gwt, plugins

I just downloaded Eclipse Indigo for Win XP.  After successfully installing the M2Eclipse plugin, I tried to install the Google Plugin for Eclipse, using this URL as my download site -- http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7.  When prompted, I selected all packages to be installed.  Android said it couldn't be found ...

```
(com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android.feature.feature.group 2.4.2.relr37v201110112027)
  Missing requirement: Android Cloud Tooling 2.4.2.relr37v201110112027     (com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android 2.4.2.relr37v201110112027) requires 'bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 12.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Google App Engine Tools for Android 2.4.2.relr37v201110112027 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android.feature.feature.group 2.4.2.relr37v201110112027)
To: com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android [2.4.2.relr37v201110112027]
```

so I skipped it to get to this screen.

http://screencast.com/t/XK81svWmcMr

When I clicked "Next", I was greeted with a screen that asked me to accept License agreements.  Even though I accepted everything, the "Finish" button was never enabled ...

http://screencast.com/t/JIEVqGKveMeU

Can someone tell me how to get past this so I can install the Google Plugin tools for Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

Google has added the Google App Engine (GAE) Tools for android in it's Google Plugin for Eclipse (GPE).
This is for integration of App Engine with Android, the fact that you are getting that error is because Android SDK is downloaded seperately, and in this case GPE expects to find that SDK on your system. To fix your problem just exclude GAE Tools from the list of modules inside GPE at the module choice screen(The screen before Install details).

Answer (score 1):

As I you have to install ADT Plugin for Eclipse first: http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html
Then you'll be able to install "Google App Engine Tools for Android 2.4.2"